# Why do I get an error when trying to use _init_?

Tags: python, python-3.x, initialization, init

So I was just trying to do the same basic classes example from python.org in my Python 3.7.0 IDLE (Shell), and when I tried to run this code:

```
class Giraffes:
    def _init_(self, spots):
        self.giraffe_spots = spots

gerald = Giraffes(100)
```

It gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#69>", line 1, in <module>
  gerald = Giraffes(100)
TypeError: Giraffes() takes no arguments
```

Doesn't the init function in class `Giraffes` make Gerald take parameter `self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [constructor method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) (like other Python [magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames)) is called `__init__` (two underscores on each side).