# Class error:TypeError: Veicolo() takes no arguments

Tags: python, runtime-error

```
class Veicolo:
def _init_(self,marca,modello,colore,prezzo):
    self.marca=marca
    self.modello=modello
    self.colore=colore
    self.prezzo=prezzo
def scheda(self):
    x="In sede ho una {} modello {} di colore {}".format(self.marca,self.modello,self.colore)
    return x
def prezzi(self):
    x="Il veicolo di {} modello {} costa {}".format(self.marca,self.modello,self.prezzo)
    return x
v1=Veicolo("fiat","punto","rosso","500")
```

print(v1.scheda())

This is the code, when i run this the shell give me the title'error, I assumed that the problem is the constructor but i don't know how to repair. I've just controlled the other question, that is similar to mine, but i don't result nothing

Comment: Everything except the first and last line of that file needs to be indented.  Otherwise, the functions are not part of the class.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: It should be `__init__` (double underscore `__`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an error when trying to use \_init\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163528/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-trying-to-use-init)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is indentation error as well as, it should be `__init__()`. Everything else is fine. Edited code would be:

```
class Veicolo:
    def __init__(self,marca,modello,colore,prezzo):
        self.marca=marca
        self.modello=modello
        self.colore=colore
        self.prezzo=prezzo
    def scheda(self):
        x="In sede ho una {} modello {} di colore  {}".format(self.marca,self.modello,self.colore)
        return x
    def prezzi(self):
        x="Il veicolo di {} modello {} costa {}".format(self.marca,self.modello,self.prezzo)
        return x

v1=Veicolo("fiat","punto","rosso","500")
print(v1.scheda())
```